# Is there adult content in A.W.: Phoenix Festa?

Tags: ps-vita

The upcoming brawler **A.W.: Phoenix Festa** seems to include dating as part of the gameplay, but I can't find the age restrictions of this game. Since its not a pure visual novel there is no page on vndb. **Is this a Hentai Action game, or Brawler with romantic side story? Or is there multiple versions of it for different age groups?**